# Dynamically Update Page Content

Tags: wp-query

I am building a golf club website in WP and I want to place a current golf course status on the home page.
This will be one or two lines of text only displaying something like this...

"The golf course is currently open and trollies can be used." or maybe something like this..

"The back 9 holes are currently closed for course maintenance. They will be open again tomorrow morning."

I want someone, possibly one of the green staff, who may not be familiar with WP to be able to update this text easily without going into the admin dashboard, locating the page and changing the text.
They may have to do this on their phone for example on arrival at the course in the morning if it is flooded for example and need to close the course.

I want a simple way for them to be able to update the text. When members view the homepage on the golf club website they will be able to see the course status that has been updated.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Regards

Alan

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option I can think of is to add a text field option to the customizer. You can have the staff member install the [WordPress App](https://apps.wordpress.com/mobile/) on hes or her phone to adjust the text on the fly when necessary.